# Show that two matrices with the same eigenvalues are similar

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

First assume that $A$ and $B$ are $p \times p$ matrices and that $\lambda_1,\ldots , \lambda_p$ are distinct eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$. I want to show that $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Here is my approach: 
The goal is to show that there is a nonsingular $p \times p$ matrix  $P$ such that $B = P^{-1}A P$.
We know the following is satisfied for each eigenvalue
$$ A \textbf x_j = \lambda_j \textbf x _j  \text { where } j = 1,\ldots,p$$
and $\textbf x_j$ are the eigenvectors. Since $A$ and $B$ share the same eigenvectors, $B$ must satisfy the following 
$$ B \textbf x_j = \lambda_j \textbf x _j  \text { where } j = 1,\ldots,p$$
Thus we have
$$ B \textbf x_j = A \textbf x_j$$
We can take the $\textbf x_j$ as the columns of the matrix $P$ and get
$$BP=AP$$
we know that the columns of $P $ are linearly independent so the matrix must be non singular. Unfortunately this means that 
$$A=B$$
but this is not what we wanted to show. Am I on the right track? Is there an obvious mistake I am making?

Comment: We know that $A$ and $B$ share the same eigen*values*, but not necessarily the same eigen*vectors*

Comment: it would be if you can change the eigenvalues in the title to distinct eigenvalues to better reflect your question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The idea in your approach almost works. But you cannot assume that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvectors! So you will have
$$
Ax_j=\lambda_jx_j,\ \ \ By_j=\lambda_jy_j. 
$$
As $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_p$ are distinct, $x_1,\ldots,x_p$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_p$ are each linearly independent, so they are bases. Let $P$ be the change of basis $y\to x$, i.e. $P$ is the matrix such that $Py_j=x_j$, $j=1,\ldots,n$. It is clearly nonsingular: if $P(c_1y_1+\cdots+c_py_p)=0$, then
$$
0=c_1P(y_1)+\cdots+c_pP(y_p)=c_1x_1+\cdots+c_px_p,
$$
so $c_1=\cdots=c_p=0$. Now, for each $j$,
$$
PBy_j=\lambda_j Py_j=\lambda_jx_j=Ax_j=APy_j.
$$
As the $y$ are a basis, we get that $PB=AP$, i.e. $PBP^{-1}=A$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, though I think there is a misplaced equals sign when showing that $P$ is non singular

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Comment: The one step that is a bit confusing, is the last one. You say that  $y$ are the basis, but why does that mean they drop out of the equality?

Comment: change of basis should be y to x

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I think what @maths was saying is that you want $Py_j = x_j$, not $Px_j = y_j$.  That, or you want $BP = PA$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Another way to proceed is to note that there is an invertible $p \times p$ matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}AS = {\rm diag}(\lambda_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{p})$ and there is an invertible $p \times p$ matrix $T$ such that $T^{-1}BT = {\rm diag}(\lambda_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{p}).$
Then $TS^{-1}AST^{-1} = B,$ and we can take $P = (ST^{-1}).$

Answer (score 4):

Be careful! If A and B are $n\times n$ matrices having the same p distinct eigenvalues where $p<n$ this argument doesn't work. Because in this case the base change matrix P would be a $p\times p$ matrix and we cannot multiply an $n \times n$ matrix with a $p\times p$ matrix.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score -1):

Two matrices with same eigenvalues are similar if they are non-singular! If the matrices are singular they may or may not be similar!

eg:
  $$M_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$
 $$ M_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

here $M_1$ & $M_2$ have the same set of eigenvalues! but they are not similar.

Comment: This is not correct mathematically.  Suppose we take $M_1,M_2$, which have the same eigenvalues but are not similar (as you say), then add a positive multiple of the identity to make them both invertible, e.g. $M_1+I,M_2+I$ are both invertible and have the same "non-similarity" as your example.

Comment: Note that the Question postulates that $A,B$ are $p\times p$ matrices which share the same $p$ distinct eigenvalues.  This is sufficient to guarantee $A,B$ are similar (since both are diagonalizable to the same diagonal matrix $D$).

Comment: @hardmath The "counter-example" provided in this answer seems to use the fact the zeroes are the only eigenvalues of a nilpotent matrix. And that two nilpotent matrices are similar iff they have same order. In this case, these two nilpotent matrices have different order and hence, not similar. However, I think this doesn't dispute the claim in question because that clearly says "distinct eigenvalues".

Comment: @Nothingspecial "two nilpotent matrices are similar iff they have same order." Only with the order of nilpotentcy being [the order of the matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339142/proof-that-all-n-times-n-matrices-that-are-nilpotent-of-order-n-are-similar) (or more trivially, nilpotency order $1$).

Comment: @hardmath I am sorry. I was ignorant when I made that comment. However, it's true that "if two nilpotent matrices are similar, they must have same order." See [nilpotent matrices up to similarity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4865035/how-many-nilpotent-matrices-are-there-in-m-n-mathbb-r-up-to-similarity). All nilpotent matrices have the same characteristic equation $x^n=0$ and eigenvalues all zeroes yet they are not similar based on the block partition of their Jordan normal form.

Comment: @hardmath what you have stated is also true for $n-1$ i.e., All $n\times n$ nilpotent matrices with order of nilpotence $n-1$ are similar. As you see there's only one partition with $n-1$ on the lead, it's $n=(n-1)+1$. I would say your "only" is now complete (we also have this besides the trivial and order $n$ case).

Comment: Anyways, my initial reaction was too fast. $M_1$ and $M_2$ are **not** nilpotent. They **do** share the same characteristic equation and hence, the same eigenvalues i.e., $0$, $0$, $1$. As the answerer noted, $M_1$ and $M_2$ are not similar. However, this **does not dispute** the claim in the original post; The criteria of distinct eigenvalues is not met. $0$ is a repeated eigenvalue of both $M_1$ and $M_2$.