# Proof that all $n\times n$ matrices that are nilpotent of order $n$ are similar.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone give a proof that all $n\times n$ matrices that are nilpotent of order $n$  are similar?

A matrix $A$ is called nilpotent if there exists some positive integer $k$ such that $A^k$ is the $0$-matrix. The order of nilpotency of a matrix is the smallest $k$ with this property. That is, the question is about matrices such that $A^n=0$ yet $A^{n-1} \neq 0$.

I am new in linear algebra and know up to linear transformation and isomorphisms and matrix representation of transformations. The same question is answered in this site using Jordan Matrix and other things which I do not know. So can anyone give a proof using elementary things which I know.

Comment: That can't be true. $0$ is a nilpotent matrix and if $A$ is similar to zero then $A=P0P^{-1} = 0$...

Comment: @Yanko Presumably, "order $n$" means that $A^n=0\neq A^{n-1}$. A confirmation would be nice, though.

Comment: You won't be able to answer it without developing *essentially* the Jordan form, or pretending you don't know it and in practice constructing the appropriate basis ad hoc. You're better off waiting until you *do* have the necessary tools so that you can understand the argument in its proper context.

Comment: I restored the mention of "order" in the post, which was removed by a third-party edit. I also added a clarification, since the terminology seems standard enough to me and it cannot reasonably refer to the dimension of the matrix (another possible meaning) since that's already given. The only other reasonable interpretation I could think of is that OP asked something impossible *and* added redundant mention of the matrix size that happened to make the question correct, which seems a bit unlikely, and even if so not much is lost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix that is nilpotent of order $n$, then there is a non-zero vector $x$ such that $A^nx =0$ but $A^{n-1}x \ne 0$. So $\{ x,Ax,A^2x,\cdots,A^{n-1}x\}$ is a basis, and the representation of $A$ with respect to this basis has a standard form. This standard form is the same for any such matrix, which makes any two such matrices similar.

Comment: That's... Just much easier than my approach. I have no idea why I didn't just start in that end.

Comment: Could you explain why $\{x, Ax, \dots, A^{n-1}x \}$ is a basis resp. why it is linearly independent?

Comment: @Diglett : If $\alpha_0 x + \alpha_1A x + \cdots + \alpha_{n-1}A^{n-1}x = 0$, then apply $A^{n-1}$  to conclude that $\alpha_0=0$. Continue in this way to conclude that all $\alpha$'s are $0$.

Comment: @Arthur : For $x$ as I have given, $\{ x,Ax,A^2x,\cdots,A^{n-1}x\}$ is a basis. The representation of $A$ using this basis has a canonical form.

Comment: You're right. Apparently I need to use the sleep.

Answer (score 6):

First a lemma: Consider the chain
$$
\ker(I)\subseteq \ker(A)\subseteq\ker(A^2)\subseteq \cdots\subseteq\ker(A^n)
$$
of subspaces of $\Bbb R^n$ (or $\Bbb C^n$ if these are complex matrices). Only the last kernel is the whole space, and the first kernel is the zero space. I claim that each inclusion is strict, and as a consequence the dimension has to increase by exactly $1$ each step.

*Proof of claim:* Assume that for some $k$ we have $\ker(A^k)=\ker(A^{k+1})$. Let $v\in\ker(A^{k+1})$. Then $Av\in\ker(A^{k+1})=\ker(A^k)$, which is to say $A^k(Ak)=0$, so $v\in\ker(A^{k+1})$. This shows that $\ker(A^{k+1})=\ker(A^{k+2})$, and by induction we see that in the chain above, from $\ker(A^k)$ on, there is only equality. Since $\ker(A^{n-1})\neq\ker(A^n)$, equality can't happen before then.

**Corollary:** $\ker(A^k)=\operatorname{im}(A^{n-k})$. And in particular, $A$ maps $\ker(A^{k})$ surjectivity onto $\ker(A^{k-1})$.

Now for the actual proof: Let $v_1$ be a non-zero element in the kernel of $A$, and let $v_k$ for $1< k\leq n$ be such that $Av_k=v_{k-1}$. In other words, let $v_2$ be such that $Av_2=v_1$, and so on (by the corollary above, such a vector can always be found). Finally, let $V$ be the matrix where the $k$'th column is $v_{k}$ (so that $v_1$ is the rightmost column). Then
$$
V^{-1}AV=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&1&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Why must the rank of $A^k$ decrease at each step, is it possible that for some $k$, $rank(A^k)=rank(A^{k+1})$?

Comment: @NazimJ If that happens, then we also have $rank(A^{k+1})=rank(A^{k+2})$, and so on. Since the rank must reach $0$ at $A^n$, and no earlier, we can't have this happen for $k<n-1$.

Comment: Maybe the 'why' of "then we also" is what is unclear. // I added the explanation on the order in OP. If you want you could remove it here.

Comment: @NazimJ if the rank of $A^{k+1}$ is equal to that of $A^k$, then the restriction of $A$ to the image of $A^k$, $A|_{\operatorname{im}(A^k)}: \operatorname{im}(A^k) \to \operatorname{im}(A^k)$ is an isomorphism.  It follows that for any $n$, 
$$
A^n|_{\operatorname{im}(A^k)} = (A|_{\operatorname{im}(A^k)})^n: \operatorname{im}(A^k) \to \operatorname{im}(A^k)
$$
will be an isomorphism and therefore non-zero.

Comment: @NazimJ I reformulated the answer to use intermediate results that are more directly related to the problem at hand. Maybe they are easier to understand too.